# Performance implications of nesting multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query I'm writing that needs to run on both SQL Server and MySQL that involves performing a very lengthy calculation. If I write it all in one query, it involves a ton of copy and pasting and redundant, hard-to-maintain code. Therefore, I wrote a much more compact version that essentially looks like this:

```
SELECT calc3...
FROM 
(
  SELECT calc2...
  FROM
  (
    SELECT calc1...
    FROM original_table
  )
)
```

Are there any reasons to believe this will lead to poor performance? e.g. will each select cause SQL Server or MySQL to create an additional temporary table behind the scenes, thereby tripling the execution time?

The calculations don't involve querying any additional tables, just adding up column values, mapping integers to strings, etc.

I only have access to a small testing dataset, so I can't run it and time it, since it takes less than a second to run with the small dataset. And I don't have permissions to view the execution plan. So I'm not sure how to go about verifying that this won't be a disaster, performance-wise. (I can test it on copies of the productive databases, but it's a long and painful process)

EDIT: just to be clear, I will be testing this on copies of the production databases, I'm just hoping to see if there are any obvious pitfalls here before I do so, as doing so will be a time intensive process. e.g. if I were calling ALTER TABLE a bunch of times, someone might point out that ALTER TABLE can be extremely slow for MySQL, so combining it all into one call or avoiding it altogether would be advisable

EDIT2:

The table in question looks like this:

```
pid     Name
1       Value1
1       Value2
1       Value4
2       Value2
2       Value5
3
4       Value1
4       Value1
4       Value4
```

and it needs to be transformed into a table like this:

```
pid     Output
1       'Many values'
2       'Two and five'
3       'Missing'
4       'Values 1 and 4'
```

where the values in the Output column are based on what values a given pid has in the Name column in the first table. Unfortunately it is not possible to derive these values by concatenating Name values or anything like that, they are fairly idiosyncratic and all need to be defined individually.

My code, with some simplifications, looks like this:

```
SELECT pid,
CASE
    WHEN TotalValues > 3 THEN 'Many values'
    WHEN TotalValues = 2 AND Value2 = 5 AND Value5 = 1 THEN 'Two and five'
    WHEN TotalValues = 2 AND Value1 = 1 AND Value4 = 1 THEN 'Values 1 and 4'
    WHEN TotalValues = 1 AND Value1 = 1 THEN 'Only value 1'
    When TotalValues = 0 THEN 'Missing' 
    -- About a dozen more of these combinations
END as OutputValue
FROM
(
    SELECT *, Value1 + Value7 as TotalValues
    FROM
    (
        SELECT distinct p.pId
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN rc.Name = 'Value1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Value1,
        -- more of these that I'm omitting for concision
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN rc.Name = 'Value7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Value7,
        FROM primary_table AS p 
        LEFT JOIN rc on rc.code=p.code
        WHERE p.desiredRecords = TRUE
        GROUP BY p.pid
    ) t1
) t2
```

EDIT3:

Result of running MySQL query profiler in SQLYog

[image: MySQL explain results]

Comment: Be a sport and post TEXT RESULTS of EXPLAIN SELECT (rest of your query).  That way, we can at least verify you are NOT using SELECT * from any table, have WHERE's that are meant to reduce data selected, JOIN's have indexes on each side of the = and many other details.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sadly I don't have the ability to call EXPLAIN. However, I did add an edit with a simplified version of my code if you happen to want to take a look. In any case, I don't think my code should run into any of those issues you mentioned

Comment: Can you get to MySQL Command prompt and SELECT NOW();  ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Aha, just remembered I could get someone else to run EXPLAIN for my in MySQL. I've added an image of the results - looks like MySQL is in fact creating three temporary tables, so that could definitely add to the total execution time...I'd be all ears if you see anything else noteworthy

Comment: Great, thanks for new posts.  Could you post A) SHOW CREATE TABLE primary_table; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE rc; and whatever ro really is.  Will check back in my morning - about 16 hours.

Comment: Legally, I don't think I'll be able to do that - this will be running on a database of a company whose database structure is itself considered proprietary. If (just guessing here) the concern is about the join using unindexed columns, that's something I won't be able to fix, but I know from experience that the datasets won't be large enough for a couple unindexed joins to be an issue

Comment: Please post the QUERY used for the EXPLAIN that was posted.  With no SHOW CREATE TABLE info, it limits our ability to determine WHY you are unhappy with the time required.  If you can not make an index on your test system to demonstrate a reduction in the time required to complete, how can you be of value to your customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries.  With the more recent versions, it does not *always* do this.  But there is a general tendency to avoid unnecessary subqueries for this reason.

SQL Server and other databases are much more sophisticated in their optimization techniques.  I am not aware of anything in SQL Server that spurs the materialization of subqueries.  If you look at the execution plan for a complex SQL query, you will be hard-pressed to figure out where the subqueries are.  So, in most databases, I would not worry about it.

CTEs are a different matter -- you don't ask about them, but they are a natural follow-on.  Some databases never materialize CTEs.  I think some always materialize CTEs.  And some sometimes materialize them.  For that, you need to be sensitive to the database and version that you are using.

Comment: Thanks, this is super informative and gives me a good idea of things to look for when we start testing

Answer (score 0):

> I only have access to a small testing dataset, so I can't run it and
>   time it, since it takes less than a second to run with the small
>   dataset. And I don't have permissions to view the execution plan. So
>   I'm not sure how to go about verifying that this won't be a disaster,
>   performance-wise. (I can test it on copies of the productive
>   databases, but it's a long and painful process)

That's the problem you need to fix.  Strangers' speculation on the performance of imaginary queries on multiple database engines is nothing to go on.